# Can't get script to run from systemd service

Tags: linux, services, systemd

I'm trying to set up a systemd service in Debian11 Stable to ultimately set up a timer. For some reason even though I can run the script manually, when I run the service nothing happens. This is /etc/systemd/system/alarm.service

```
[Unit]
Descrption=Alarm

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/jason/Documents/music.sh
User=jason
```

This is /home/jason/Documents/music.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
audacious /home/jason/Documents/music.mp3
```

I am reloading the daemon after any edits to the service with

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

This is how I am trying to run the service

```
sudo systemctl start alarm.service
```

I am following a youtube tutorial in which he creates a time & date stamp into a file which works fine for me but when I try and actually run something I get no errors but no results. I suspect it's more the script than anything wrong with the service.